# jq del: Remove elements from a list

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I want to delete the entries in a JSON list that have the "enabled" key with the value `false`.

The following jq cmd does select the false entries but now I want to remove those entries and keep the rest of the structure.

```
jq '.app.sig[] | select(.enabled==false)'  app-test.json
```

Example JSON input

```
{
  "app" : {
       "id" : "11111111",
       "name" : "test",
       "general" : {
           "allow" : "sdasdass",
       },
       "settings" : {
           "max" : "8192",
       },
       "sig" : [
           {
               "enabled" : true,
               "Staging" : false,
               "sId" : "200101556"
           },
           {
               "enabled" : false,
               "Staging" : false,
               "sId" : "200012071"
           },
           {
               "enabled" : true,
               "Staging" : false,
               "sId" : "200012002"
           },
       ],
       "version" : "v1",
   }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please remove trailing commas from objects' and arrays' last items to make it a valid JSON input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIth a valid JSON input it's straightforward using `del` and `select`:

```bash
del(.app.sig[] | select(.enabled | not))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/aYTxP3JefIY)

Alternatively, use `map` to reset the array with what you want to keep:

```bash
.app.sig |= map(select(.enabled))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/if3aIr-TBxP)

In both cases, you can directly use the (possibly negated) boolean value within `select`. Output:

```json
{
  "app": {
    "id": "11111111",
    "name": "test",
    "general": {
      "allow": "sdasdass"
    },
    "settings": {
      "max": "8192"
    },
    "sig": [
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "Staging": false,
        "sId": "200101556"
      },
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "Staging": false,
        "sId": "200012002"
      }
    ],
    "version": "v1"
  }
}
```